# File upload to Web API2 not working with Angular CLI (Webpack) proxy

Tags: angular, file-upload, webpack, asp.net-web-api2, angular-cli

***Setup:***

- OS: W10 Pro
- Server: Web API 2 (.Net 4.5.2) hosted in IIS 10.0
- Client: Angular 4.2.4 (Angular CLI 1.4.9)
- API Url: localhost/site/api
- NG Url: localhost: 4200

I have an Angular CLI app that utilizes the built in (Webpack) proxy to call MVC and Web Api 2 services while in development.  The app will live in the MVC app in production.  All HTTP calls work great and get through the proxy just fine except when I try to POST a file from an input[file], both in FormData and directly.

I get the following error in console:

```
POST http://localhost:4200/site/api/import/fileUpload/225/1 net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

...and this in the .catch for the .post:

```
Response with status: 0  for URL: null
```

Here's the relevant code:

### file-upload.service.ts

```
public startFileUpload(importdata: IFileImportData, files: any[] = []) {

    importdata.files = files.map((file: any) => {
        return {name: file.name};
    });

    let url = `${environment.apiUrl}import/setup`;
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    this._http.post(url, importdata)
        .map(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(`FileUploadService > import/setup > Error: ${error}`);
            return error;
        })
        .subscribe(
            key => {
                // options.headers.set('Content-Type', undefined);
                options.headers.set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
                // options.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

                files.forEach((file: any, index: number) => {
                    let url = `${environment.apiUrl}import/fileUpload/${key}/${index + 1}`;

                    let formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append('file', file, file.name);

                    let req = this._http
                        .post(url, formData, options)
                        .map(response => {
                            return response.json();
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.log(`FileUploadService > import/fileUpload > Error: ${error}`);
                            return error;
                        })
                        .subscribe();
                    // this._addUploading(key, req);
                });
            },
            error => {
                console.log(`FileUploadService > Error: ${error}`);
            }
        );
}
```

*files: any[] is an array of files selected by an input[file] in the component*

---

Generally, when you see the error **Response with status: 0  for URL: null** it's a CORS issue, but if I comment out the line to add the file to the FormData (and even add other values to FormData) it works.  I can hit the API endpoint, get the intended response, and all seems right with the world.  This tells me it's not a CORS issue, but something else.

I have several other locations where I am posting values and objects to the API with no issue.  It is only the file upload scenario that's causing me problems.

Just to ensure it's not an Angular issue, I created a XMLHttpRequest and tried posting it directly.  No dice.

Any Ideas?

---

Note: I can't use CORS on the server side (even in dev) due to application security restrictions etc. etc.

---

Comment: no need for the disclaimer. by posting this question, you are assumed to have done the research. The disclaimer won't stop anyone from downvoting your question (if it even needs downvoting… seems like a legit question to me).

Comment: Did you down vote the question because you didn't like the disclaimer? Really?

Comment: I didn't down vote. As I said, it seems like a legit question to me.

Comment: Someone did, and it's not showing me who or why.  I took alot of care to NOT post until I had exhausted all other avenues and then to write the question as completely as possible without including unnecessary information due to how vindictive and elitist people are on this site.  

. ...but still, someone would rather down vote it than contribute to a solution.  
That's pathetic.

Comment: Unfortunately, but understandably, the StackExchange network does not show you who votes or how they vote for reasons exactly like this. They don't want you hunting them down and taking out revenge. [This is by design.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299493/how-can-i-know-who-has-up-voted-and-who-down-voted) Every once in a while you will ask a question that gets a few downvotes. Don't stress over it. If it's a good question, you'll get more ups than downs. If not, most decent users will provide feedback in the comments. If it makes you feel any better, I'll upvote.

Comment: Thank you.  It us much appreciated.  I have encountered many griefers on this site over the years, and it's left me a bit jaded to a site that started off so well as a center of information sharing and assistance, but has grown many thorns and become less than welcoming in many cases.  I am still hopeful though.

Answer (score 1):

After extensive testing and ignoring the useless messages I was getting from .Net, I found that the requests were getting to the server and getting rejected terminated instead of rejected.  The reason for this was the lack of redundant configuration.  Since the .Net app is being virtually hosted in IIS, I not only needed the query size config for the app, I also need a slightly different version of this same configuration for IIS...  for some strange reason.

Anyway, here's the lines I had to have:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"  maxUrlLength="40960" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
</system.web>
```

AND

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" maxQueryString="2097151" maxUrl="40960"/>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

After adding this, it all started working just fine.

Side note:
I also had to delete the "Content-Type" header from the request since Angular doesn't add the "boundary" metadata correctly if the content-type is set.

```
options.headers.delete('Content-Type');
```

...hope this saves someone some time and pain.

Comment: I think increasing the maxAllowedContentLength is not always the best solution. You can afford to increase the default value on your side, but in general, its's really important to perform an analysis of the IIS machine before changing this value.